# Process multiple element using asyncio instead of threads

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a program that uses python threads like this:
starting 5 threads and start processing a list of elements.

```py
def process_element(element):
   print(element)

jobs = Queue()
    
def do_stuff(q):
    while not q.empty():
        value = q.get()
        process_element(element=value)
        q.task_done()
 
for i in line: # my list of element
    jobs.put(i)
    
for i in range(5):
    worker = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(jobs))
    worker.start()

jobs.join()
```

How can I use [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) to do the same work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly do you struggle?

Comment: when i try to migrate to asyncio i don't know how to translate my code to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal translation of your code into asyncio would look like this:

```
import asyncio, random

async def process_element(element):
    print('starting', element)
    await asyncio.sleep(random.random())  # simulate IO-bound processing
    print('done', element)

async def do_stuff(q):
    while not q.empty():
        value = await q.get()
        await process_element(element=value)
        q.task_done()

async def main():
    jobs = asyncio.Queue()

    for i in range(20):
        await jobs.put(i)

    for i in range(5):
        asyncio.create_task(do_stuff(jobs))

    await jobs.join()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Note, however, that:

- Asyncio handles IO-bound tasks such as communicating with HTTP servers or remote databases, chat servers, etc. It doesn't handle CPU-bound tasks, where a long-running operation will block the whole event loop. (In such cases multithreading or multiprocessing are more appropriate.) For this reason "converting" multithreaded code to asyncio often fails.
- `while not q.empty(): ... process ...` is an anti-pattern in both threading and asyncio because it doesn't allow waiting for something to arrive in the queue. If you know all your items in advance, you don't need a queue in the first place, you could use ordinary lists.

Comment: yes I know all my element before starting the process